# Ziggy conflict with Vue Router

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a console warning from Vue.

```
[Vue warn]: Methods property "route" is already defined in Props. 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

I am aware that there is a conflict between two packages. Is there a way to eliminate this warning?
The packages I'm using are:
https://github.com/tighten/ziggy
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router

Answer (score 0):

Open the ziggy.js configuration file in your project

Locate the route method in the configuration object:

```
const Ziggy = {
    route: ...
};
```

Rename the route method to something else, such as generateRoute:

```
const Ziggy = {
    generateRoute: ...
};
```

Save and reload the application

Comment: There is no such a file as ziggy.js